# How to create an issue in jira using java rest api

Tags: java, rest, jira-rest-api

I have checked almost every link but could not find the proper solution for it.
I need to create an issue in JIRA using java rest api.
Code :-

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URI;
  import java.net.URISyntaxException;
  import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
  import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
  import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.BasicProject;
  import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
  import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.ServerVersionConstants;
  import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactor;


public class TestingRestAPI {
    private static URI jiraServerUri =
 URI.create("https://vgsvdgteam.jira.com/rest/api/2/project");
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
JSONException, IOException {
  final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new 
                                        AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
      final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "liasia","cooki123!!");
           try {
            final int buildNumber = restClient.getMetadataClient().getServerInfo().claim().getBuildNumber();
             System.out.println("---------------------------------"+buildNumber);
            // first let's get and print all visible projects (only jira4.3+)
            System.out.println("Print all print all visible projects:");
            if (buildNumber >= ServerVersionConstants.BN_JIRA_6) {
                final Iterable<BasicProject> allProjects = restClient.getProjectClient().getAllProjects().claim();
                for (BasicProject project : allProjects) {
                    System.out.println(project);
                }
            }
            // then print one issue details
            System.out.println("Print issue TST-63239");
            final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("TST-63239").claim();
            System.out.println(issue);
        }
        finally {
            restClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Dependency added in pom.xml  :-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Exception getting :-

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(404), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=404, errors={}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.DelegatingPromise.claim(DelegatingPromise.java:47)
    at com.citrix.restjira.jiratest.TestingRestAPI.main(TestingRestAPI.java:25)
Caused by: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(404), errorCollections=[ErrorCollection{status=404, errors={}, errorMessages=[]}]}
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.internal.async.AbstractAsynchronousRestClient$2.apply(AbstractAsynchronousRestClient.java:160)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:48)
    at com.atlassian.httpclient.api.ResponsePromiseMapFunction.apply(ResponsePromiseMapFunction.java:12)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$Of$3.apply(Promises.java:285)
    at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.Promises$2.onSuccess(Promises.java:162)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$7.run(Futures.java:1072)
```

After checking the exception it seems the claim() function of Serverinfo class  has the problem.
Or the URL has any issue ?
Can some help me to overcome this issue or any useful link?

Answer (score 0):

I'll share with you a code i use to create issues in Jira using `IssueInputBuilder` class:

```
    JiraRestClient restClient;

    public boolean createIssue(IssueJiraDTO issueDTO) throws IOException{

            final IssueInputBuilder builder = new IssueInputBuilder(PROJECT_KEY, issueDTO.getIssueType(), issueDTO.getSummary());
            final ComponentRestClient componentClient = restClient.getComponentClient();

            try {

                openClient();

                //completamos los datos
                Component component = componentClient.getComponent(new URI(issueDTO.getComponent())).claim();
                builder.setComponents(component);
                builder.setFieldValue(CODCESCEFIELDID, issueDTO.getCodcesce());
                builder.setFieldValue(LINKCAFIELD, issueDTO.getLinkCA().trim());
                builder.setFieldValue(SECURITYFIELD, ComplexIssueInputFieldValue.with("id",  issueDTO.getSecurityLevel()));
                builder.setPriorityId(issueDTO.getPriority());
                builder.setDescription(issueDTO.getDescription());
                final IssueInput input = builder.build();

                // create issue
                final IssueRestClient client = restClient.getIssueClient();
                final BasicIssue issue = client.createIssue(input).claim();
                logger.info("Incidencia creada correctamente: "+ issue.getId());

            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error("Error al crear la Issue en Jira: " + issueDTO.getCodcesce(), e);
            } finally {
                closeClient();
            }

            return true;
        }
```

openClient basically do:

```
restClient = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory().createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(JIRA_URL), JIRA_ADMIN_USERNAME, JIRA_ADMIN_PASSWORD);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks ...But what is restClient and openClient method defined here?

Comment: Thanks..Very helpful. can you share something about IssueJiraDTO issueDTO?

Comment: `IssueJiraDTO is just a custom bean with the data to be inserted in the issue. IF it was useful, you could accept my answer @Littlebird :D

Comment: I tried your code with some modification but still getting the same exception :(

Comment: `404` means not foud, so maybe your url is wrong, or the service is down in `https://vgsvdgteam.jira.com`

Comment: Actually , i have edited the URL here , but in my code i'm using the right URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88364/discussion-between-fran-montero-and-little-bird).