# Creating a new "JIRA issue" using REST API in java

Tags: java, rest, jira, jira-rest-java-api

Hey guys  i am really struggling with this, i would like to create new JIRA issues using java through the REST API but every example i have seen is incomplete or doesnt work for me like this one:
[How to create an issue in jira using java rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308456/how-to-create-an-issue-in-jira-using-java-rest-api)

Any help, sample code or link to the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**I think this sample code is helps u**

> This is totlly working for me

```
 public static String invokePostMethod() throws AuthenticationException, ClientHandlerException, IOException {

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/latest/issue");                 

    String data = "{"fields":{"project":{"key":"DEMO"},"summary":"REST Test","issuetype":{"name":"Bug"}}}";

    String auth = new String(Base64.encode(Uname + ":" + Password));
    ClientResponse response = webResource.header("Authorization", "Basic " + auth).type("application/json").accept("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, data);
    int statusCode = response.getStatus();

    if (statusCode == 401) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid Username or Password");
    } else if (statusCode == 403) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Forbidden");
    } else if (statusCode == 200 || statusCode == 201) {
        System.out.println("Ticket Create succesfully");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Http Error : " + statusCode);
    }
    // ******************************Getting Responce body*********************************************
    BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntityInputStream()));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);

    }
    return response.getEntity(String.class);
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the comment and sorry fot the late reply can you tell me which libraries you are using?

Comment: use this maven discrepancies                                                                     

    <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: Hey i'm sorry i havent answered you sooner i was away the code you gave me seems to work as i get the right response but im not logged in i get this :  <input type="hidden" title="ajaxUnauthorised" value="You are not authorized to perform this operation.  Please log in.">                                                     Thanks a gain for all your help